# PHP $_POST variables between functions in a class

Tags: php, class, post

I can get the $_POST variables in the next function once, but when repeating the function or going to the next function the variables aren't accessible. I am using PHP class and multiple functions. I have searched and haven't found the solution. Maybe I am missing something simple. I am new to using classes in PHP, and also $_POST variables. I am unclear why they aren't accessible within some functions. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    }

$MainPage = new MainPage();
$MainPage->showMainPage();

class MainPage
{   
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function showMainPage()
    {   

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }   

        echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        echo "<html>";
        echo "<head>";
        echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";

        echo " </head>";
        echo "<body>";

        $showmainoptions = 0;
        if (isset($_GET['showmainoptions'])) 
        {
            $showmainoptions = $_GET['showmainoptions'];
        }

        $showFinOptions = 0; 
        if (isset($_GET['showfinoptions'])) 
        {
            $showFinOptions = $_GET['showfinoptions'];
        }   

        $showInspectionList = 0; 
        if (isset($_GET['showinspectionlist'])) 
        {
            $showInspectionList = $_GET['showinspectionlist'];
        }           

        if($showmainoptions)
        {
            $this->showMainOptions();
        }

        if($showFinOptions)
        {           
            $this->showFinOptions();

        }
        if($showInspectionList)
        {           
            $this->showInspectionList();

        }           


        $this->showFooterHTML();
        return;

    }

    public function showMainOptions()
    {   

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
        echo "Select Main Options<br>";
        echo "<form name=\"submitMainOptions\" id=\"submitMainOptions\" method=\"post\" action=\"mainpage.php?showmainoptions=0&showfinoptions=1&showinspectionlist=0&addnewinspection=0\">";
        echo "<label><font size=4px>Wharehouse</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"house\" name=\"house\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"CYP\">Cypress</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"FAY\">Fayetville</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"FUR\">Furnace</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<label><font size=4px>Fin Type</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"fintype\" name=\"fintype\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"Copper\">Copper</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"Aluminum\">Aluminum</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<label><font size=4px>Shift</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"shift\" name=\"shift\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"1\">Shift 1</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"2\">Shift 2</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"3\">Shift 3</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat\">Continue</button></a>";          
        echo "</form>";

    }

    public function showFinOptions()    
    {
        $house = $_POST['house'];   
        echo $house."<br>";
        echo "Select Fin Options<br>";
        echo "<form name=\"submitFinSelection\" id=\"submitFinSelection\" method=\"post\" action=\"mainpage.php?showmainoptions=0&showfinoptions=0&showinspectionlist=1&addnewinspection=0\">";
        echo "<label><font size=4px>Part No</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"partno\" name=\"partno\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"partno1\">partno 1</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"partno2\">partno 2</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"partno3\">partno 3</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<label><font size=4px>Fin Size</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"finsize\" name=\"finsize\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"5mm\">5mm</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"7mm\">7mm</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<label><font size=4px>Press No</font></label> ";
        echo "<select id=\"pressno\" name=\"pressno\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
        echo "<option value=\"CF016\">CF016</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"CF018\">CF018</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"CF020\">CF020</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat\">Continue</button></a>";

        echo "</form>";

    }


    public function showInspectionList()    
    {

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        $house = $_POST['house'];   
        echo $house."<br>";
        $pressno = $_POST['pressno'];
        echo $pressno."<br>";


    }

public function showFooterHTML()
{   
    echo "  </body>";
    echo "</html>";     


    return;
}


}

?>
```

Comment: may i ask why you require to echo every line of html in php?

Comment: which class methods have the issue? (this code is an abomination, so maybe fix that next :-))

Comment: Both methods have the issue. By navigating to one then back to the other the variables are not accessible.

Comment: Echoing every line of html is the style used by the group, not my choice.

Comment: if navigation as mentioned above means a page reload - that's the issue, all variables are lost between reloads, unless you explicitly store the data somewhere

Comment: OK, so the 2nd time a form is processed, the action is reloading the page and then the prior $_POST variables are gone. And does $_SESSION variables behave the same?  Storing the data somewhere...is it common to store in database, or is there a better option? thanks

Comment: no $_SESSION variables are stored on the server on a per user bases

Comment: thanks, I will try using $_SESSION instead. I tried it earlier, but maybe I did something wrong